# Finding a particular object in an array mongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a collection that is composed of some strings, objects, and one array.  Within that array are several objects.  I am attempting to remove all of the orders with the object id of ObjectId("587ec66e5ed5cb0061092dbe"). See below for the schema and related data.  I have tried everything under the sun.

```
var campgroundSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   name: String,
   image: String,
   description: String,
   price: String,
   author: {
      id: {
         type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
         ref: "User"
      },
      username: String
   },
   orders: [
      {
         type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
         ref: "Order"
      }
   ]
});
```

Below is sample data.

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("587ec65e5ed5cb0061092dbd"), 
    "name" : "is Forrest Cool?", 
    "price" : "", 
    "image" : "https://dsafd.com", 
    "description" : "", 
    "orders" : 
    [ 
        ObjectId("587ec66e5ed5cb0061092dbe"), 
        ObjectId("587ec6bc5ed5cb0061092dc0"), 
        ObjectId("587ec6c05ed5cb0061092dc2"), 
        ObjectId("587ec7178f628931610636dc"), 
        ObjectId("587ec71e8f628931610636de")
    ], 
    "author" : { "id" : ObjectId("587ec6145ed5cb0061092dbc"), 
    "username" : "forrest" }, 
    "__v" : 18 
}
```

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find the specific element with particular `ObjectId` inside `orders` array, You can use `$in`.

**Try this:**

```
//orderObjectId is the object id you want to find inside orders.
Campground.find({orders : {$in : [orderObjectId]}},{'orders.$':1},function(err,result){
...
});
```

`'orders.$':1` will return only that element from orders array

To delete that particular order,

```
//_id is optional, you can query using orderID also.
Campground.update({ 
    _id :someObjectId, orders : {$in : [orderObjectId]}
},{
    $pull : {order : orderObjectId}
},function(err,result){
                     ...
});
```

**Update:**
Accroding to your comment, it seems you are having facing problem using this.

Try this:

```
//if you are receiving orderId as string, convert string to ObjectId
var orderId = mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId("587d78b8e898d1e732b3888a");

Campground.find({"orders": {$in : [orderId]}},function(err, result){ 
   if(err){ 
       console.log(err); 
   } else { 
       console.log("FOUND RESULT: " + result); 
   } 
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, Ravi. However, I still cannot figure it out. As you can tell, I am brand new to node/js/mongo.  Can you provide something I can easily copy and paste into my code to see if that helps.  I am looking for the order that has the objectId of "587d78b8e898d1e732b3888a".

Comment: what is the problem you are facing?

Comment: Campground.find({"orders._id":"587d78b8e898d1e732b3888a"}, function(err, result){
                          if(err){
                              console.log(err);
                          } else {
                              console.log("FOUND RESULT: " + result);
                          }
                        });

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: Please dont use simple string to query ObjectId, it will give you error

Comment: It no longer throws an error, but it is returning no results.  However, I know there is an object id with that value in the orders.

Comment: what is your query criteria?

Comment: `Campground.find({orders : {$in : [orderObjectId]}},{'orders.$':1},function(err,result){});` try this, and save `OrderId` in `orderObjectId` variable before this query. also `console` the `result` in the callback.

Comment: I could not get the find to work, but the remove did! Thank you.